# Can I pass user input to my constructor

Tags: java

So I've got the following two classes, I am trying to pass user input into my constructor, thoughts?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class CampingSystem {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            NewCamper a = new NewCamper();
            Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Input Customer First Name");
            String fName = b.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Input Customer Surname");
            String lName = b.nextLine();


            System.out.println(a.getCamperName());

        }

}
```

Then I've also got the class and constructor:

```
public class NewCamper {
    String first;
    String last;

    public String getCamperName() {
        return ( first +" "+ last);
    }

    NewCamper(){
        first = "Ben";
        last = "lloyds";
    }

}
```

Comment: why not? create one parameterized constructor for NewCamper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. You just have to implement a constructor that receives the parameters you want and uses them and then call that contstructor instead. Easy as pie. :-)

```
NewCamper(String firstName, String lastName){
    first = firstName;
    last = lastName;
}
```

and

```
NewCamper a = new NewCamper(fName, lName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing! Create a constructor

```
public NewCamper(String first, String last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}
```

Then in CampingSystem

```
Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input Customer First Name");
String fName = b.nextLine();

System.out.println("Input Customer Surname");
String lName = b.nextLine();

NewCamper a = newCamper(fName, lName);

System.out.println(a.getCamperName());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your NewCamper class, build a constructor that receives the parameters that you want

```
public class NewCamper {
    String first;
    String last;

    public newCamper(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.first = firstName;
        this.last = lastName;
    }

    public NewCamper() {
        first = "Ben";
        last = "lloyds";
    }
    public String getCamperName() {
        return ( first +" "+ last);
    }
}
```

Then, in your Camping System class, call that constructor with the code:

```
NewCamper person = new NewCamper(fname,lname);
```