# How to pass user input to constructor in java

Tags: java, user-input

So I was just testing some things out first before I do my actual homework.
My goal is to have the user enter his/her name, course, and student number, right?

now the activity said to have a "student" object.

now, I want to pass those user inputs to the constructor and display it.

unfortunately, there is an error "non-static variable cannot be referenced" (this is my first time getting this error)

Also, I kinda based my on this post here:
[Can I pass user input to my constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680649/can-i-pass-user-input-to-my-constructor)

any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {

int student_num;
String name, course;

public Student (String n, String c, int sn) {
    name = n;
    student_num = sn;
    course = c;
}




    public static void main (String[]args) {

    Student pupil = new Student(name, course, student_num);  

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Name:");
            String name = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter Course:");
            String course = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter Student Number:");
            int student_num = input.nextInt();


            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Name:" +name);
            System.out.println("Course:" +course);
            System.out.println("Student Number:" +student_num);



System.exit(0);   

}

}
```

Comment: Java is an Object oriented programming. You need to have an object to call the methods or use the properties of it (non-static). Unless you want to have something which should not care about object (static).

Comment: Just move the line `Student pupil = ...` to below `int student_num = input.nextInt()`.

Comment: You should create a Student object to store in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with this line `Student pupil = new Student(name, course, student_num);`

You reference instance variable here from static context...so it doesn't work. 
Actually this line must be the last one when you got all input from user and you create new student from these input.

Comment: I am so sorry I don't follow...  So I put the object last?? Is it possible to get an example?

Comment: Just take this line and put it below all the lines. Your construction will work now because local variables will be used instead of reference instance variables(defined at class level)

Comment: It's okay now THANKS!